# How to find the manufacture of a integrated sound card?

Tags: audio

I helped my friend to re-install windows XP on his old computer but the integrated sound card could not be recognized.  As he forgot the manufacture of the sound card, I don't know to how to find the correct driver.

Is there any software that could help us to identify the manufacture of the card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get the model of the motherboard, search the manufacturer's website and it will probably tell you which integrated card is on the board. The driver download page for the motherboard will have it listed under sound as well more than likely.

Comment: Then how to get the model of the motherboard?

Comment: Screwdriver + eyeballs

Comment: Or read POST messages / check BIOS. I Like @Mike's method better though :)